# continuous async file I/O in .Net

Tags: .net, wpf, asynchronous, io

i have a WPF application which need to a continuous file I/O. The problem i have is that this need to be done in the background. 
More Details about the app: I have data coming in 3 times per second(blocks of 14000 doubles). This data need to be stored on disk right away and need to be further modified and showed in the GUI. And by pressing a button the user can trigger to read the complete file( first i thought to read only a specific block of the file but this is not possible) and send the data to GUI.
The problem is i don't know how to do this.
First i thought about Backgroundwoker. But this will not work because i have to start it every time a new block comes in.
I hope one of you can help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: With .Net 4.5+, use `Task.Run(() => SaveDataBlockToDisk(data))` to start asynchronous data saving. Use `var fileData = await Task.Run(() => ReadTheCompleteFile())` to read data without blocking UI.

Comment: @Sam: But if i want to do that with the same file at the same time i will get an error. right?

Comment: Concurrent file access is entirely depends on your realization of `SaveDataBlockToDisk` and `ReadTheCompleteFile` methods, and it is extremely [famous task](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=c%23+concurrent+read+write+file) to be a problem... You can also use database if you know that you always work with data of particular type with particular size, this approach will do all concurrency job for you. I just demonstrated solution to your phrase "The problem i have is that this need to be done in the background".